# How can I search the SMSs/MMSs using the default search interface?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, mms, google-search, sms

I have a Cyanogenmod 10.1 ROM installed. I love the Google Search interface and can search most of my phone using it, but I am unable to find "Messaging" as a searchable item. I've seen a lot of photos showing "Messaging" as a searchable item, but it isn't on my phone.

I dug through the Cyanogenmod source and found that [a commit](https://bitbucket.org/cyanogenmod/android_packages_apps_mms/commits/15290a70177d1cca473fb40e9eee3ed76249926c) was made that removed this functionality. I haven't been able to understand the reason for this.

Is it possible to re-add this feature? Do I need to configure something?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help or not, but if you need this option, you can give it a try (if you are ready to face the aftermath whatever it is).

First, you have to access the system files of your mobile, so you might need
[Droid Explorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer). You may face an error sometime while showing the android SDK path if you have already installed it on PC. For that, you can simply create a folder named `android-7` inside your `sdk/platforms` folder.

Then connect your phone and open Droid Explorer and try locating the particular `searchable.xml` file which I have no idea where it is.

Open it and try changing the `false` into `true`.

Sometimes, it might have triggered some other file to change this particular option. I tried myself for some time using this and I couldn't figure it out.